# Check an enum can be created from a parameter in a switch

Tags: swift, enums, switch-statement

I have an enum something like...

```
enum MyEnum {
    case a(Foo)
    case b
    case c(Bar)

    enum Foo: String {
        case one
        case two
    }

    enum Bar: String {
        case three
        case four
    }
}
```

I'm trying to create a fail-able initialiser function for this so that you can call it like...

```
MyEnum(base: "a", parameter: "one")
```

or

```
MyEnum(base: "b", parameter: nil)
```

I've got it working (but it's clunky) like this...

```
init?(base: String, parameter: String?) {
    switch (base, parameter) {
    case ("a", let p?) where Foo(rawValue: p) != nil:
        self = .a(Foo(rawValue: p)!)
    case ("b", _):
        self = .b
    case ("c", let p?) where Bar(rawValue: p) != nil:
        self = .c(Bar(rawValue: p)!)
    default:
        return nil
    }
}
```

This will switch on the `base` and then check that the next value can be created before entering the case.

However, I have to now create the `Foo` or `Bar` twice and force unwrap the second one.

Is there a way to get the switch case to create the `Foo` or `Bar` and only enter the case if it can be created so that I can just use that one that was created and not have to create a second one?

Comment: You have `"a"` in switch twice, is it typo?

Comment: @RobertDresler, ~~those cases have different `where` predicates, they're not the same.~~ Oh wait, second should be "c".

Comment: Don't make it too complicated. Switch on `base`, and for the cases "a" and "c" do `if let p = parameter, let foo = Foo(rawValue: p)` (or `guard let ...`) .

Comment: Or skip the `switch` statement and only use `if` ones: `if base == "a", let p = parameter, let foo = Foo(rawValue: p)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't make it too complicated. Switch on the `base` value, and handle the `parameter` where needed, with `if` or `guard` and optional binding:

```
init?(base: String, parameter: String?) {
    switch base {
    case "a":
        guard let p = parameter, let foo = Foo(rawValue: p) else { return nil }
        self = .a(foo)
    case "b":
        self = .b
    case "c":
        guard let p = parameter, let bar = Bar(rawValue: p) else { return nil }
        self = .c(bar)
    default:
        return nil
    }
}
```

Easy to understand, no forced unwrapping, and the  `Foo` or `Bar` values are only created once (if needed).

It also minimizes the tests: As an example, `MyEnum(base: "a", parameter: nil)` would go to the `"a"` case and return `nil`. In your switch statement it would fail to match the `("a", let p?)` case and then still check the remaining cases.

Comment: Also, there's no need in temp `p` variable, just  `let foo/bar = parameter.flatMap(Foo/Bar.init)` will do.

Comment: @user28434: That's an alternative, but I find this easier to read (surely opinion-based).

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to `switch` over both `Foo` and `Bar` initializers:

```
init?(base: String, parameter: String?) {
    switch (base, parameter.flatMap { Foo.init(rawValue: $0) ?? Bar(rawValue: $0) } as Any?) {
    case ("a", let foo as Foo):
        self = .a(foo)
    case ("b", _):
        self = .b
    case ("c", let bar as Bar):
        self = .c(bar)
    default:
        return nil
    }
}
```

The downside is that if `Foo` and `Bar` share common cases, then you might not get the outcome you want. Also if the number of cases increase, so might the expression on the `switch`.